# Are tow truck drivers allowed to be armed while working?

Tags: united-states, florida, firearms, towing

[Florida Tow Truck Driver kills man while trying to repossess a car.](https://wsvn.com/news/local/broward/new-video-shows-man-shot-and-killed-by-tow-truck-driver-during-car-repossession-in-fort-lauderdale-neighborhood/?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter_wsvn)

- Are tow truck drivers allowed to be armed while repossessing a car?
- Does any other state allow tow truck drivers to be armed?

Comment: States don’t allow you to do anything, they can only pass laws to restrict your liberty.  This may seem like a minor distinction, but it isn’t.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tow truck drivers in general might be allowed to carry firearms if they have a concealed weapons license, but the shooter in the case at hand wasn't merely a tow truck driver.  He was actually repossessing a car, and therefore under [Florida Statutes 493.6101(21)](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0400-0499/0493/0493.html) he was acting as a *recovery agent*.  Under 493.6401 he was therefore required to hold a Class "R" recovery agent license.  And under 493.6118(1)(x)(9), Class "R" license holders are prohibited from:

> Carrying any weapon or firearm when he or she is on private property and performing duties under his or her license whether or not he or she is licensed pursuant to s. 790.06.

The story says that the car was in a driveway, so it sounds like he was on private property.  This would be grounds for discipline under 493.6118(2), up to and including revocation of his license.

It could be that criminal penalties also apply, but I have not found them so far.

Answer (score 0):

Open carry in public is illegal for everyone in Florida. Concealed carry is allowed if you have a concealed weapons license. There is an age requirement (21 years old) and a required firearms training course, see [Fla. Stat 790.06](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0790/0790.html) for the complete law. There are no employment restrictions (e.g. "a school teacher cannot be issued a permit; a tow-truck driver cannot be issued a permit").

No state forbids tow truck drivers to carry weapons.

Comment: Can you cite the law against public open carry?  Because that tends to be legal in the U.S.  Only FL gun laws I know is from my boss who got a gun for home defense and when he was registering it with the cops, was told by the cop "Remember, if God forbid you have to use that weapon on a home invader, shoot to kill *beat* it's less paperwork for us."

Comment: @hszmv , 790.053 Open carrying of weapons.—
(1) Except as otherwise provided by law and in subsection (2), it is unlawful for any person to openly carry on or about his or her person any firearm or electric weapon or device.

Comment: Open carry is legal in florida while hunting, fishing, or camping..